Movie about a newspaper editor vs. a crooked businessman/politician? "The press is running"
I'm looking for an American movie, English language, probably in black and white.  I guess it's from the 1950's or so...
It's about a newspaper editor (or possibly a journalist) who takes on a crooked businessman (or possibly a politician).  The newspaper is close to bankruptcy or being bought up, but despite this, the paper investigates the businessman.  The businessman tries different things to stop the newspaper.  There may have been a mafia/organized crime connection.
Towards the end, it's clear that the edition exposing the businessman/politician will be the newspaper's last.  It ends with the businessman calling the editor and threatening him, and the editor lifting the handset so it can take in the sound of the printing-press before he says "Do you hear that?  The press is running!" (or something like that).
Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Deadline USA (1952) with Humphrey Bogart

Ed Hutcheson is the crusading managing editor of a large metropolitan newspaper called The Day. He is steadfastly loyal to publisher Margaret Garrison, the widow of the paper's founder, but Mrs. Garrison is on the verge of selling the newspaper to interests who plan to permanently cease its operation.
Hutcheson has other concerns, including that his estranged wife Nora is about to remarry. He also puts his reporters to work on the murder of a young woman and the involvement of racketeer Tomas Rienzi, which could turn out to be a circulation builder that keeps the paper in business or else the last big story it ever covers.




